# Push notification in Android using Everlive

Tags: kendo-ui, push-notification, kendo-mobile, everlive

I am creating hybrid application using Kendo UI Mobile. I want to have push notification with my application. I try to enable notification on simulator and on physical device (kindle fire HD) but it is not working.

As a reference I am using this post: http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-07-08/introducing-push-notifications-services-push-for-hybrid-apps-made-easy

Its bit of confusing because I am not able to understand how push notification is working.

Also, I had create project on GCM for android and enter API in Everlive i.e. Telerik Backend Services.

Can anyone help me with the instruction how to get Push notification with Kendo UI Mobile (i.e. VS 2012 extension) and Backend services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you refer to the AppBuilder’s VS extension and the push notifications for hybrid apps. The Kendo UI framework is not relevant to the push notifications client-server interaction.

In fact, there is a more up-to-date article on integrating push notifications in a hybrid app built with Telerik AppBuilder and Telerik Backend Services. You can find it [here](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/sample-apps/sample-backend-services-pushnotifications). By following it you will be able to get the things up and running and deploy to an Android device (notifications will not be received in the simulator).

It is noteworthy to know that when you create a push message in Backend Services, it is dispatched to the respective push notifications servers (in the case of Android – Google Cloud Messaging). Kindle Fire HD cannot receive notifications from GCM, which is why you do not receive the notifications on the device.